# Estou fazendo certo este exercício?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Até então estou conseguindo fazê-lo, porém o método `imprimiAgenda()` está imprimindo, mas ao mesmo tempo dando null pointer. E também quero saber se minha lógica está indo bem. Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço! Uma outra dúvida, como faça para fazer os getters e setters de arrays? Pois o setter até consegui fazer, sem problema algum, já o getter dava problema, pois ele precisava de um retorno.

```
package exercicio;
public class Agenda {
     private String nome[] = new String [5];
     private int idade [] = new int [5];
     private float altura [] = new float [5];


public void armazenaAgenda (String nome, int idade, float altura) {
    for (int c=0; c<=5; c++) {
        if(this.nome[c] == null || this.nome[c].isEmpty()) {
        this.nome[c] = nome;
        this.idade[c] = idade;
        this.altura[c] = altura;
        break;
        } 

    }
}



public void imprimiAgenda () {
    for (int c=0; c<=5; c++){
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome[c]);
        System.out.println("Idade: " + this.idade[c]);
        System.out.println("Altura: " + this.altura[c]);
        System.out.println("------------------");

    }
}

public void buscarIndex(int i) {
    for (int c=0; c<=5; c++ ){
        if(this.nome[c] == this.nome[i]) {
            System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome[i]);
            System.out.println("Idade: " + this.idade[i]);
            System.out.println("Altura: " + this.altura[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void buscarNome (String nome) {
    for (int c=0; c<=5; c++){
        if (this.nome[c] == nome) {
            System.out.println(nome + " esta na posicaçao: " + c);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma boa orientação a objeto poderia ser você criar uma classe, digamos, `Pessoa`. Dentro dela, você teria então os atributos `nome`, `idade` e `altura`, encapsulados com _getters_ e _setters_. Então, na classe `Agenda`, em vez de 1 _array_ para cada atributo, como é hoje, você teria um único _array_, de `Pessoa`. Com relação a sua lógica atual, você terá problemas nos `for` por causa da condição de parada dele. Veja se consegue entender por quê.

Comment: so uma coisa, nessa parte aqui:
     if(this.nome[c] == null || this.nome[c].isEmpty())
é para checar se o campo da string[indice] = esta vazia pra assim ser preenchida com this.nome[indice] = nome; entendeu ? como faço para checar se a String no indice X, esta vazia sem usar esses operadores == =!

Comment: sim, o Objects.equals. Porem ele verifica se sao iguais e nao nulas, mas eu quero ao contrario, eu quero saber se sao nulas, se for nulas, e vazias preencher...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há alguns erros. O principal erro é que você não deve usar `==` ou `!=` para comparar `String`s. Use o método `equals`. para evitar ter que se preocupar com o caso de um deles ser `null` no método `equals`, você pode usar `Objects.equals(a, b)`.

Assim sendo, no lugar disso:

```
        if(this.nome[c] == this.nome[i]) {
```

Você deveria usar isso:

```
        if (Objects.equals(this.nome[c], this.nome[i])) {
```

E também, no lugar disso:

```
        if (this.nome[c] == nome) {
```

Você usaria isso:

```
        if (Objects.equals(this.nome[c], nome)) {
```

Os seus laços também estão com os limites errados:

```
for (int c=0; c<=5; c++){
```

Era para ser isso:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
```

Há ainda um outro problema. Você não deveria usar um `for` no método `buscarIndex`, afinal o índice já é lhe dado como parâmetro. Bastaria fazer isso:

```
public void buscarIndex(int i) {
    System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome[i]);
    System.out.println("Idade: " + this.idade[i]);
    System.out.println("Altura: " + this.altura[i]);
}
```

Há outras coisas que poderia ser consideradas. Em especial seria uma boa ideia ter uma classe `Contato` com `nome`, `idade` e `altura` e também getters e setters e então fazer a `Agenda` ter uma `List<Contato>`, o que também te livra da restrição de ter o tamanho máximo da agenda fixo em 5 e também facilitaria bastante operações de adição, remoção e busca de contatos na agenda.

Comment: Talvez, verificar se o indice não é maior que o limite do array, já que o método e o proprio array fazem parte da mesma classe. Já evitaria arrayindexofboundexception.

Comment: Apesar de que eu faria essa verificação fora da agenda e não internamente.

Comment: @Articuno Na verdade eu faria um `return contatos.size() < i ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(contato.get(i));` - mas o OP ainda está bem longe de poder entender isso.

Comment: Não faço idéia do que seja isso. :D

Comment: @Aricuno Armazenaria os contatos numa lista e usaria `Optional<Contato>` como retorno do método.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Estou iniciando e aprendendo,muito importante a sua resposta para o meu desenvolvimento. No intuito de praticar, eu procurei exercícios na internet de java poo, a ideia era essa, cria uma agenda com o limite de 5, que teria os métodos getters e setters de nome,altura, idade e também um que armazene esses três atributos, removesse, procurasse pelo nome e procurasse pelo índice